# Concatenating several values where the type has a Show instance

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I want to write a function `showAll` that takes a `List` of values and produces a `String` obtained by concatenating the `String` representations of each of the values, using the `Show` instances available in implicit scope.

There should be no constraint on the type of the elements of the list, other than the presence of the `Show` instance.

For example:

```
case class Person(name: String)
implicit val showPerson: Show[Person] = Show.by(_.name)
showAll(List(1, Person("Martin")))
```

should output:

```
1 Martin
```

In this case the function is using `Show[Int]` and `Show[Person]` instances.

What would be a proper signature for the function?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the **List** is of type `List[Any]` for which there is no `Show` no a simple way to have the `Show` of each element. There are a lot of tricks to get what you want, from the **magnet** pattern, to creating a custom class that zip each element with its show instance, to using **Shapeless** to do the zipping automatically.

Comment: Indeed, that's the problem. My first thought was to add some common supertype T and then write a show instance for T, but I was wondering if I could solve it just by enhancing the signature somehow. Shapeless looks interesting.

Comment: Check [this _(search for the section called "Bonus Round: How do we deal with collections?")_](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) - If you manage to get it working please post an answer! :)

Comment: Do you insist on `List` or varargs would also work for you? Like `showAll(1, person)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code , which probably solve your problem.
I have created generic method show all as you require to show elements of List. also an implicit method for specific field values. MyClass trail is identifier. if Myclass won't extended by any case class specific field wont be printed.

```
trait Myclass
  case class Person(name: String) extends Myclass
  case class Admin(name: String,age:Long) extends Myclass

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    showAll[Myclass](List(1, 2, Person("Martin"),Admin("Bob",30)))
  }

  implicit def showField: String = "name"

  def showAll[T <: Myclass : ClassTag](listOfValues: List[Any]): Unit = {
    listOfValues.foreach { data =>
      if (data.isInstanceOf[T]) {
        val myInstance= data.asInstanceOf[T]
        val fld = myInstance.getClass.getDeclaredField(showField)
        fld.setAccessible(true)
        val value = fld.get(myInstance).asInstanceOf[String]
        print(value + " ")
      }
      else
        print(data + " ")
    }
  }
```